# Difference in creation between Inner and Subclass

Tags: java, inheritance, nested, subclass, inner-classes

I noticed that to make **Inner** class we need instance of **Outer** class. But to also make a **Subclass**, we need **Parent** class to create instance, as well.

What is difference between them if there is some? Strictly speaking in *creation* and not *how they work*. Can I picture it: there is object of **Parent** and inside it is **Child** object, same as **Inner** class object is inside **Outer** class's object in heap? Am I any close to this?

Comment: @Hades Nope, I just came from that question.. I am targeting creation and objects, not functionality.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe a picture/analogy to represent the two relationships:

[image]

i.e.:

- `janeDoe` the subclass instance is just one object, but it's both types in one instance.
- `johnDoe`, the inner class instance, is distinct from `janeDoe`, the outer class instance. They have a very close link and, between them, they know how they use each other.

Comment: Awesome answer, thanks mate! Only one little concern (in subclass example). Why is super class constructor always called when there is no super class object in your diagram? Aren't constructors responsible for creating new object? So why is there no `new Mother()` as well?

Comment: @Stefan I only mentioned constructor calls that we make explicitly when creating objects (i.e., I omitted all other constructor calls made by the class itself, explicitly or not). Think of it as instantiations (one instance is created irrespective of how many local or inherited constructors will run).

Comment: Ah I think I get it, but not totally. Sorry, I am not so good at this :) But if you had made a complete picture, there would have to be Mother object when creating Daughter?

Comment: @Stefan no need to be sorry. I knew there was a risk of the picture showing some ambiguity. The best way to think about the left side is *a daughter picks up all the genes and behaviors of a mother by virtue of being a woman too, but a daughter can stand alone as a person*. But a fetus cannot stand alone (a mother instance is needed), and the fact that a fetus can have genes/behaviors of the mother is irrelevant in this case - that's why I made it `johnDoe`, a male :-) . I'll change Mother/Daughter to something more precise.

Comment: @Stefan I think the woman/mother analogy is more accurate than mother/daughter. I've updated the picture.